# Bitfield value changes when sent over socket C++

Tags: c++, sockets, bit-fields

I have a bitfield that looks like the following:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) MyStruct {
  unsigned int val1:14;
  unsigned int val2:1;
  unsigned int val3:1;
  unsigned int val4:1;
  unsigned int val5:1;
  unsigned short aFullShort;
  unsigned int aFullInt;
} MyStruct;
```

I am sending these values over the network and have noticed that sometimes the sender will think that `val1` is set(verifiable by printing the value prior to send) but the receiver will not see that `val1` is set. The code for transmission is as follows:

```
MyStruct* myStruct = new MyStruct(); //initialize fields here
sendto(sock, myStruct, sizeof(MyStruct), 0, ...);
```

The code for reading is as follows:

```
unsigned char theBuffer[sizeof(MyStruct)];
recvfrom(aSocket, &theBuffer, sizeof(theBuffer), 0, ...);
```

After reading in the bytes from the socket, I reinterpret cast the bytes to a `MyStruct` and perform endian conversion for `aFullShort` and `aFullInt`. The corruption occurs such that the receiver thinks that `val1` is 0 when the sender set it to 1. Why might this happen? Might the compiler be inserting different padding for the sender and receiver? Do I need to worry about the endianness of the single bit values?

Comment: Are sender/receiver same OS and exact same compiler.  Bit field layout is implementation defined.

Comment: @RichardCritten the sender and the receiver are run on the same host and compiled using the same compiler. Two seperate binaries are created for the sender and the receiver, which might enable the compiler to make different optimizations for the two targets.

Comment: Do a dump of `(char*)(void*)myStruct` in the sender and a dump of `theBuffer` in the receiver. Are the bytes the same? If so,it points to structure layout differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can lay out bit fields however it wants. It can randomize them on every execution if it wants to. There is absolutely no rule that prohibits this. If you want to serialize data in a predictable binary format that you can rely on, write code that does that.

The sole exception would be if your compiler has some specified guarantee for packed structs and you are willing to confine yourself to only that compiler. You don't specify the compiler you're using, but I doubt that it does.

There is really no reason to write code like this. You want to write code that is guaranteed to work by the relevant standard(s), not code that might happen to work if nothing happens to break the assumptions it makes.

Comment: Although bit field layout is implementation specific, it has to be consistent. If you write a bit field to a file, and later read the file with the same implementation, you should get back the same values. It can't be random.

Comment: @Barmar Why do you say that? I understand why you would expect it to happen to be consistent. But what makes you think it "has to be" consistent? Does the C++ standard say so? Does POSIX? Does your compiler documentation?

Comment: because if it isn't, bit fields can't be used for communication between anything in separate compilation units. They couldn't be used in arguments to libraries, etc.

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't work that way. You're making up circumstances in which you think it would fail and then concluding that it therefore can never happen. Suppose the compiler could tell that this bit field never crossed a library boundary. Or say the format for bit fields was set randomly on boot up of the machine. You're trying to prove something can't happen by imagining ways that it happening *might* fail and therefore assuming it *never* happens. That's just wrong. Either you have a guarantee from a relevant standard or you don't.

Comment: Sure, the as-if rule allows it to do anything if you can't tell the difference. But my example was that you're calling a function in a separate compilation unit, so that "suppose the compiler could tell" doesn't apply, so it has to be consistent with whatever happened when it was compiled. Bit fields are implementation-specific, just like `int` size is implementation-specific, but the size of an `int` can't change within an implementation.

Comment: @Barmar Did you read the "Or say the format for bit fields was set randomly on boot up of the machine" part of my response? But in any event, it doesn't matter. You can't synthesize a guarantee this way because our imagination is limited. The compiler is simply not required to make this work, and under the as-if rule, it can make things it is required to make work come out okay without making stuff it isn't required to make work happen to come out right. Either you can find a guarantee in a relevant standard or it's not guaranteed.

Comment: I read that part, I just find it difficult to believe it's true. Can you refer to the part of the spec that says that an implementation can be inconsistent? I don't care about the as-if case where the layout isn't detectable, only the case where the bit field is used for communication between compilation units or across time.

Comment: There's a long painful list of things that people assumed would always work despite never being guaranteed that suddenly stopped working when things people couldn't think of happened. This is not unavoidable -- all you have to do is not write code like this that relies on guarantees you don't actually have. The spec doesn't have to say an implementation can be inconsistent -- an implementation only has to be inconsistent if some spec says so. And there are many examples of code that broke because the implementation was inconsistent about things other than data representation.

Comment: And of course you shouldn't use them over sockets, since you can't assume the other system will be compiled with the same implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157941/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-barmar).